# Creating a community wiki question on purpose?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Following on from Aarons answer [here](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/155/253), can I create a question like "What are some on line network engineering communities and how can I access them?" - Purposefully so that I can create a community wiki answer that people can add to?

So I am thinking of creating the question, the posting an answer with a list of mailing lists and web sites etc, and marking the answer as a community wiki for others to extend. Is this permissible within the Network Engineer rules?

Answer (score 1):

I know that list questions are generally discouraged across the Stack Exchange network; however *some* communities allow them, e.g. [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list)... so I guess it's not completely out of the question, and its up to *us* as a community to decide; maybe the Community Managers have an opinion about whether it's too early to define such scope of the site, however.

*Personally*, I don't think this sort of post is for us; this is a Q/A board to answer specific questions, not a reference site for everything networking.

With this particular post, it's hard to draw the line IMO; what about geographical communities? Who decides when a community is *large*, *helpful* enough (to who?) to be added to the list?

Furthermore, these posts *very* quickly end up being a [big](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books), [unwieldy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read) list, generally without any sorting or organisation, and very quickly becomes unusable (can you tell I'm not a fan? :P).

As for *how* to do this; you can post CW answers right from the off, but to make a *question* CW, you have to flag it for moderator attention and specifically ask a moderator to CW it for you. Answers to a CW *question* are automatically CW'd upon submission.

Comment: +1, That is a good point about the scope of the list and who will moderate it and regulate the input etc. I guess it is asking for trouble. My reasoning is that it would save people asking questions about network engineering communities.

Comment: @javano: I would argue that those sorts of questions would be off-topic for this site anyway; they're hard to form without encouraging either a "big list" response, or subjective responses about which community is *best* / *most appropriate*.

Answer (score 0):

**no, off-topic**

meh. CW/big-lists questions aren't a good fit.

**...but what about posting such questions in Meta?**

Search engines will still find it, and it will remain a useful resource for us to mention/link-to in comments/answers of normal questions.

I browsed through all the current meta questions and we don't yet have anything like this (a CW/long-list Q and As.) So we'd be breaking new ground as far as this stack is concerned.